# Random Number Choosing On React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx

I am doing a Netflix Clone and I need to change the Banner in every page refresh. I integrated movie details from TMDb. So I want to choose a random number between 0 and 19. I need that random number to display the movie on banner by the number in an array. This array contains movie details.  I used `Math.random()` function and an error came that `response` is not defined. How Do I solve This. Please Help Me.

Here Is My Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Banner.css'
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import {API_KEY,imageUrl} from '../../Constants/Constants'
import axios from '../../Axios'

function Banner() {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState()
    const results = response.data.results
    const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.rand() * results.length)
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            setMovie(response.data.results[newIndex])
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="banner" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${movie ? imageUrl+movie.backdrop_path : ""})`}}>
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="title">{movie ? movie.title : ""}</h1>
                <div className="banner-buttons">
                    <button className="button">Play</button>
                    <button className="button">My List</button>
                </div>
                <h1 className="description">{movie ? movie.overview : ""}</h1>
            </div> 
            <div className="fade-bottom"></div>                               
        </div>
    )
}

export default Banner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response is a block-scoped variable that you're attempting to access.

```
            const [movie, setMovie] = useState()

            useEffect(() => {
                axios.get(`trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`).then((response)=>{
                    const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.rand() * response.data.results.length + 1)
                    setMovie(response.data.results[newIndex])
                })
            }, [])
```

or

```
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState()

            const generateRandomNum = (max) => {
                Math.floor(Math.rand() * max + 1)
            }

            useEffect(() => {
                axios.get(`trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`).then((response)=>{
                    const newIndex = generateRandomNum(response.data.results)
                    setMovie(response.data.results[newIndex])
                })
            }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const results = response.data.results
```

This line, will obviously throw an error because at this point in the execution, response is not defined. You're only getting it later in the `axios.get().then()` callback. You'd wanna set results there, but using a variable will not work. You'd want this result to persist across renders, so store the results in state, not a constant. Instead of the above line,

```
const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
```

and then later in the .then callback,

```
setResults(response.data.results);
```

Give an initial placeholder value for your movie, maybe a loading animation, till you get the response from the axios call.

Also,

```
setMovie(response.data.results[newIndex])
```

putting the above in your useEffect will result in setting the movie only once,on mount, because the useEffect hook with an empty dependancy array functions as a ComponentDidMount().

If you want to randomly loop through the movies fetched, consider using a setInterval and generate a new random index with `Math.random()`, (not `Math.rand()` as used in the question code snippet), and render the result at that index.